how to extract dataframe values to form an array?
I have an excel sheet, which I am trying to process with Python as part of an ETL process.
I have an Excel sheet with a bunch of data in it. But the columns are not the first row on the Excel sheet, which is a dump of JIRA isssues.
file.xlsb
time stamp row.
Export  x number of issue
 Project | Summary | Creator | Status | Description | Key  (and a bunch of other fields)
data row 1 
data row 2
etc.... 

I am able to read the data with a simple Panda; however, I only need certain data, like the summary, status, key. How do I pull that data?
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(imported_file, skiprows=2)

When I try to make a Python list of the data, I get a key error:
test.py", line 3812, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'Key'

What I have so far is:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(imported_file, skiprows=2)
print(df)

issuesArray = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  issuesArray.append({
     ' Ticket #: ': row['Key'],
     ' Issue Type: ': row['Issue Type'],
     ' Issue Created: ': row['Created'],
     ' Status: ': row['Status'],
     ' Summary: ': row['Summary'],
     ' Reporter: ': row['Reporter'],
     ' Project: ': row['Project'],
     ' Body: ': row['Description']
  })
    
for entryItem in issuesArray:
  print ("---")
  print (entryItem)
  print ("---")

I tried referencing the df row using the column string and integer, both of which result in the key error. Essentially, I am looking for a list of dict items that I can easily manage in Python. Anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Verify that the column names are what they should be with print(df.columns).

To process your Excel sheet and extract specific data, ensure that the column names you are referencing in your code match exactly with those in your Excel sheet. Given that the columns are not the first row, skipping rows with skiprows=2 is correct, assuming your columns start on the third row.
Here’s a detailed solution:

Read the Excel sheet with the correct number of rows to skip.
Check the column names after reading the data.
Extract the required data into a list of dictionaries.

Step-by-Step Solution

Read the Excel file and inspect the DataFrame to ensure columns are loaded correctly:
import pandas as pd

# Read the Excel file
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsb', skiprows=2)

# Print the columns to verify correct names
print(df.columns)


Update the code to match the column names as per the printed output:
import pandas as pd

# Read the Excel file
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsb', skiprows=2)

# Assuming columns names are as follows:
required_columns = ['Key', 'Issue Type', 'Created', 'Status', 'Summary', 'Reporter', 'Project', 'Description']

# Filter the DataFrame to include only the required columns
df_filtered = df[required_columns]

# Create a list of dictionaries
issuesArray = df_filtered.to_dict(orient='records')

# Print the list of dictionaries
for entryItem in issuesArray:
    print("---")
    print(entryItem)
    print("---")


Handle possible KeyErrors if columns are not present or are misspelled:
import pandas as pd

# Read the Excel file
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsb', skiprows=2)

# Print the columns to verify correct names
print(df.columns)

required_columns = ['Key', 'Issue Type', 'Created', 'Status', 'Summary', 'Reporter', 'Project', 'Description']

# Ensure all required columns are present
for col in required_columns:
    if col not in df.columns:
        print(f"Column '{col}' not found in the Excel sheet")

# Filter the DataFrame to include only the required columns
df_filtered = df[required_columns]

# Create a list of dictionaries
issuesArray = df_filtered.to_dict(orient='records')

# Print the list of dictionaries
for entryItem in issuesArray:
    print("---")
    print(entryItem)
    print("---")



Notes

Make sure your column names in the Excel file exactly match the strings you use in the code (e.g., case sensitivity, extra spaces).
If the columns have different names or extra spaces, you may need to adjust the column names accordingly.

By following these steps, you should be able to extract the necessary data from your Excel sheet and convert it into a list of dictionaries for further processing.

HI Niket! Thanks for the info, it was very helpful. The issue that I had is that the cloumn were not being picked up after the import.   'Unnamed: 3', 'Unnamed: 4', 'Unnamed: 5', 'Unnamed: 6', 'Unnamed: 7',        'Unnamed: 8', 'Unnamed: 9',        ...        'Unnamed: 187', 'Unnamed: 188', 'Unnamed: 189', 'Unnamed: 190',        'Unnamed: 191', 'Unnamed: 192', 'Unnamed: 193', 'Unnamed: 194',        'Unnamed: 195', 'Unnamed: 196'],, the excel doc actually has 200+ columns, but I only need seven or so..... The df.columns cmd pointed that out to me.... Thanks for the help! ta, X

I got it working with ```` df = pd.read_excel(importFile, skiprows=2)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.values[1:], columns=df.iloc[0])
print(df2.columns)
print(df2) ```


Based Niket's answer....
if os.path.exists(importFile):
  print("Import File located @ " + str(importFile))
else:
  print("File does not exist!!!!")
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', 2000)
pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:20,.2f}'.format)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

pd.reset_option('display.max_rows')
pd.reset_option('display.max_columns')
pd.reset_option('display.width')
pd.reset_option('display.float_format')
pd.reset_option('display.max_colwidth')
    
df = pd.read_excel(importFile, skiprows=2)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.values[1:], columns=df.iloc[0])
    
required_columns = ['Key', 'Issue Type', 'Created', 'Status', 'Summary', 'Reporter', 'Project', 'Description']

# Ensure all required columns are present
for col in required_columns:
  if col not in df2.columns:
    print(f"Column '{col}' not found in the Excel sheet")
df_filtered = df2[required_columns]
issuesArray = df_filtered.to_dict(orient='records')


print(issuesArray)


the key is the df2 line ...
